# BizTalk+ESB using custom pipeline is throwing error trying to obtain trust#RequestSecurityToken. How do I circumvent this?

Tags: asp.net, biztalk, esb, biztalk-2020

I'm using BizTalk 2020 and ESB. I have an itinerary that does a request/response to a WCF Web Service. The itinerary does a transformation, then routes the message to the service. The service sends the message back out. A second transformation is done, on the response.

The issue is I'm getting trust#RequestSecurityToken error thrown on the receive location. The itinerary does not require an encryption certificate. The website uses anonymous authentication.

My pipeline uses ItinerarySelect and is tied to the database. Not sure why I am getting this error or how to fix it.

Pipeline components = ESBItinerarySelector, XMLDisassembler, ESB Dispatcher on [Resolve Party]

Changed the web service from Windows Authenication to None. No Change.

> Error:ystem.ServiceModel.FaultException: There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "PTwoRecMapPipeline.Part2RecPipeline, PTwoRecMapPipeline, Version=1.0.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ed4d3b3678f2ac22" Source: "XML disassembler" Receive Port: "WcfReceivePort_WCFInitiator/Service1" URI: "/WCFInitiator/Service1.svc" Reason: Finding the document specification by message type "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust#RequestSecurityToken" failed. Verify the schema deployed properly.

> Server stack trace:
> at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Security.CommunicationObjectSecurityTokenProvider.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Security.Sym

Comment: Pipeline components = ESBItinerarySelector, XMLDisassembler, ESB Dispatcher on [Resolve Party]

Comment: I'm using a common schema. I added a reference to the schema project to the pipeline. Also added the full schema information:  to Doucment Schemas in the xmlDisassembler. rebuilt and reran after verifying that the data coming in matched the schema, but  get this message : Reason: Document type "OutWCF" does not match any of the given schemas.

Comment: What is the root node and namespace of the schema?  Also please show exactly what you have configured in the XML disassembler.

Comment: The error message you have in your question does not match the one you mention in your comment.

Comment: I have gotten past the original error, the issue was with the common schema library. I have moved the schemas into the WCF application. I set the "AllowUnrecognizedMessages" to true. This got me over the original error. I'm closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten past the original error, the issue was with the common schema library. I have moved the schemas into the WCF application. I set the "AllowUnrecognizedMessages" to true. This got me over the original error. I'm closing this question.